# Removing elements from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I am having a few issues unsetting an entire row from a multidimensional array.  I have an array that takes the following format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10000
            [Date] => 21/11/2013
            [Total] => 10
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10001
            [Date] => 21/12/2013
            [Total] => abc
        )
    ...
)
```

I am looping this array to check that the Total contains only numbers or a period.

```
foreach($this->csvData as &$item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        if($key === 'Total') {
            $res = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $item[$key] );
            if(strlen($res) == 0) {
                unset($item[$key]);
            } else {
                $item[$key] = $res;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you can see from my array, the second element Total contains abc, therefore the whole element it is in should be removed.  At the moment, with what I have, I am getting only that element removed

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10001
            [Date] => 21/12/2013
        )
```

How can I remove the whole element?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Add key for outer array (no longer need to pass-by-reference)
foreach($this->csvData as $dataKey => $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        if($key === 'Total') {
            $res = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $item[$key] );
            if(strlen($res) == 0) {
                // Unset the key for this item in the outer array
                unset($this->csvData[$dataKey]);
            } else {
                $item[$key] = $res;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.  Will accept as soon as it allows me too.

Comment: One question though, if I add the outer key, why do I no longer need to pass by reference?

Comment: By default the array is copied before running through the foreach, so you need to pass by reference in order to modify any elements of the array. Here, we're operating directly on the outer array outside of the foreach, so there's no need to pass-by-reference. Note, it's not hurting anything by using pass-by-reference, just unnecessary.

Comment: Reason I asked was because it was not modifying some of my values, but I assume thats because where I am setting the new value, I need to also use datakey?

Comment: Crap, you're modifying other data within the foreach loop. You should definitely keep the pass-by-reference. Sorry!